# Trying to write a function that deletes a node

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to write a function that deletes a node from the linked list, though I was having trouble.

Here is my algorithm:

- Get the name of the node that I want to delete
  (every node has 3 details in it: name/age/gender)
- Then I find its place in the list
- and then I pass it forward

For example

> Friend -> next = friend -> next -> next..

Though I need to find the first node in the linked list, and I'm not sure how to get to it.
This is what I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct friend
{
    char *name;
   int age;
   char gender;
   struct friend* next;
}friend;
void node_delete(friend* delete)
{
 friend* temp = malloc(sizeof(friend)); 
 char name[256];
 int i = 0, j =0; // Not being used, though I'd use it
 printf ("Please enter the friend's name you want to delete: \n");
 fgets (name, 256, stdin); // Getting the name of the person the user wants to delete
 fgets (name, 256, stdin);
 while (0 == (strcmp(temp -> next -> name, delete -> next -> name))) // As long as the           
 // name doesnt match, it'll go to the next name in the linked list
 {
       temp = friend -> next; // Going to the next name in the linked list
 }
 temp -> next = temp -> next -> next; // Replacing the node with the node after it..
// for ex. if I have 1 -> 2 -> 3, it'll be 1 -> 3
 free (delete);
}
```

Comment: The while loop stops as soon as a name doesn't match; you are overwriting the first data you read into `name`; you are never putting data into `temp`, just giving it a block of memory; `i` and `j` are unused. (Try to go through and explain *exactly* what each line of that code does to yourself, that might help a bit :) )

Comment: Why do you try to get the name twice?

Comment: I've changed the loop for a 0 !=, so it'd work;
also, I'm not sure how to put something in it, that was the question...
@Redx - I've got a bug that I gotto write it twice to make it work..
This is'nt the problem, so forget about it...
Edit: I will add notes right away....

Comment: @AmitSegal, I wasn't meaning explain to us, just to yourself (or to a handy rubber duck, or other object, haha) and for it to work properly you need to explain *every* function call on every single line (like, why are there two `fgets`s?), that's the best way to pick up bugs. This is sometimes called "Rubber duck debugging", and it is a very useful skill to have (it even has a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!).

Comment: Allright, thank you for ur comment :)
P.S - I used two fgets because I've got a bug sometimes that one isnt enough... (and two fgets works like one fgets)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have had a good crack at this.

I'm not entirely sure about your question but here is what I think you might be trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct friend
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    struct friend* next;
}friend;


void node_delete(const char* name, friend* stFriend)
{
    if (!stFriend->next) //end of list
    { 
        printf("%s is not a friend!\n", name);
    }
    else if ( !strcmp(name, stFriend->next->name) ) //name matches! remove link
    {     
        //here's where you can free your unwanted friend ptr ~NB: are you sure this friend is not a friend of someone else?
        //free(stFriend -> next);    
        stFriend->next=stFriend->next->next;
        printf("%s is no longer a friend!\n", name); 
    }
    else //name does not match -recurse
    {
        node_delete(name, stFriend->next);
    }
}


void print_friends(const friend* pstPerson)
{
    if (pstPerson->next)
    {
        printf("next friend:%s\n", pstPerson->next->name);
        print_friends(pstPerson->next);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("no more friends :(\n\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    friend stFriend0, stFriend1, stFriend2, stPerson;
    char name[256]={0};

    stFriend0.name="amber";
    stFriend0.next=0;

    stFriend1.name="betty";
    stFriend1.next=&stFriend0;

    stFriend2.name="catherine";
    stFriend2.next=&stFriend1;

    stPerson.name="violet";
    stPerson.next=&stFriend2;

    printf("%s's friends before:\n", stPerson.name);
    print_friends(&stPerson);

    printf("remove a friend: ");
    fgets (name, 256, stdin);
    strtok(name, "\n");

    node_delete(name, &stPerson);

    printf("\n\n%s's friends after:\n", stPerson.name);
    print_friends(&stPerson);

    printf("\n\n\ndone!\n");

    return 0;
```

}

[online demo.](https://ideone.com/ezAVoK)

It assumes that your `node_delete(friend* delete)` function takes a person, with some friends in the linked list and removes a friend who's name matches the stdin input.

(i also added another little function so you can see how much fun a linked list can be!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should compare (temp -> next -> name) with (name), not with (delete -> next -> name)

```
while (0 == (strcmp(temp -> next -> name, name)))
```

but you should assign your temp with friendlist head

```
temp = delete;  // delete should be a pointer to root list element
```

And.. For what reason you need i and j?
Also why you use malloc()? Why not declare your struct as local stuff

```
friend* temp;
```

Try this

```
friend* temp; 
char name[256];

// receive node to delete
printf ("Please enter the friend's name you want to delete: \n");
// omg here was two fgets!!
fgets (name, 256, stdin);

// delete should be a pointer to root list element
temp = delete;    

// Check if node to be deleted is a root node
if(strcmp(temp -> name, name)==0){ 
    delete = delete->next;
    return;
}   

// go throug all the list
while (temp->next!=NULL){
   // if node was found - delete it
   if(strcmp(temp -> next -> name, name)==0) 
       temp -> next = temp -> next -> next;    
   temp = temp-> next;
}
```

There is a logical error in this code, you also need to check head node. There isn't this checking in my code. You can easy add it by yourself. Sorry. (already fixed in codeblock)

Also "delete" is the bad name for function parametr, try friendList or something like that better). Additionally isn't delete a keyword in C++?

Comment: I've fixed the cmp;
I dont, I though I would need em so I just put em in the start...
the point is, how do I put something into temp ?

Comment: I know friends and delete is a keyword, though I'm in C, and next year when I'll learn C++, I'll take that to mind, Thanks!
Also, what do you mean by delete should be a pointer to root list element? (I'm learning C in a diff language, so I'm not sure what did u ment.)

Comment: I mean that when you call this function, you should give it a pointer to the head of your list like a parameter (delete). Also there is logical error, I've described it above, directly under codeblock in answer, don't forget to fix this.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do from the first place, but I couldent figure a way how to do it...

Comment: I've added this fix to codeblock in answer for you. Hope, I've managed to help you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but you didnt answer my question.. simpley because the temp = delete line cant work to me... I'm not sure how to setup the delete in my code, as I said above...

Comment: Try to rename delete to friendListPtr in function declaration, prototype and her code. Also when you call your function, from your main or other functions you should get her via parametr address of your head(root) list node. For example [`node_delete(&myFriendListHead);`]

Comment: but what do I put in the delete ?

Comment: I think in your main function you create your list. Perhaps using malloc() function. And you should to store your head(root) list element, for executimg a job like deleting, searching, adding nodes. "Put into delete" pointer to your head node.

Comment: friend* delete = (friend*)malloc(sizeof(friend))
friend* temp;
temp = delete;
though, in the while loop, the temp = friend -> next says syntax error...

Comment: remove line [`friend* delete = (friend*) malloc ...... `], kill it, destroy like evil with saint cross and fire

Comment: so what do I do insted of this line?
i'm having a hard time understanding you guys..

Comment: It was a joke about cross, evil and fire, nvm. Insted of this line? Hey, you know it! [`friend* temp;   temp = delete;`] Just look again at codeblock in answer. Try to use it.

Comment: but delete has nothing on it!!

Comment: Use "friendListPtr" instead of "delete", if you renamed it. If you didn't, use "delete".

Comment: When you call your function, you should transmit pointer to your head node via this parameter.

Comment: Have you got a function to add node to list?

Comment: I have to go, I recommend you to google for "Linked list C" and inspect founded materials. Good luck.